# how can close ModalView after change screen in Python Kivy

Tags: kivy

I have ModelView Class and Screen classes, when open Modal View and do some things on first Screen class after change to second Screen Class but modal dismiss not work

/*İmport Moduls*/

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, partial
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
```

/*My Scroll View for putting buttons to screen1 */

```
class SView(ScrollView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)
        self.MM = MyModal()
        self.MM.MyButton=self.MyButton

    def MyButton(self, *args):
        print("Hello")

    def MMDismiss(self, *args):
        pass

    def ModalOpen(self, instance, button, *args):
        self.MM.open()
        self.MM.MyButton = self.MyButton
        self.MMDismiss = self.MM.dismiss


    def update(self, *args):

        layout = GridLayout(width=480, padding=10, cols=7, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)

        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

        self.buttons=["One", "Two", "Three","One", "Two", "Three","One", "Two", "Three","One", "Two", "Three","One", "Two", "Three","One", "Two", "Three","One", "Two", "Three","One", "Two", "Three","One", "Two", "Three","One", "Two", "Three"]


        for key in self.buttons:

            stacklayout = StackLayout(size_hint_y=None, size_hint_x=None, height=130, width=100, orientation='lr-tb')

            btn = Button(text=key, size_hint_y=None, size_hint_x=None, height=130, width=100)

            stacklayout.add_widget(btn)
            btn.bind(on_release=partial(self.ModalOpen, key))

            layout.add_widget(stacklayout)
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(layout)
```

/*when press the button of screen1 open the modal */

```
class MyModal(ModalView):

    text = StringProperty("text")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyModal, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.size = (200, 200)
        self.layout=GridLayout(cols=1,padding=10,spacing=10)
        self.layout.add_widget(Label(text=self.text))
        self.btn=Button(text="My Button")
        self.bind(on_press=self.MyButton)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.btn)
        self.add_widget(self.layout)

    def MyButton(self, *args):
       pass
```

/*My Screen1*/

```
class Screen1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sview=SView()
        self.mylayout = GridLayout(cols=1)
        self.mylayout.add_widget(self.sview)
        self.add_widget(self.mylayout)
        self.sview.MyButton = self.MyButton

    def MyButton(self, instance, button):
        self.manager.current = "screen2"
        print("screen 2")


class Screen2(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

/*my builder string*/

```
Builder.load_string('''
<SM>:
    Screen1:
        name: "screen1"
    Screen2:
        name: "screen2"

''')
```

/*my screen Manager*/

```
class SM(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SM, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.current = 'screen1'
```

/*my app*/

```
class Main(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def build(self):
        self.title = "MAVA"
        self.icon = "./images/logo/logo.png"
        return SM()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that isn't working. Try to show as little code as possible while still highlighting the issue. If we are able to copy/paste your code sample and see the error for ourselves, even better

Comment: I wil add my code thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `MyModal` class, you can add the `dismiss` to the `Button` as:

```
class MyModal(ModalView):

    text = StringProperty("text")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyModal, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.size = (200, 200)
        self.layout=GridLayout(cols=1,padding=10,spacing=10)
        self.layout.add_widget(Label(text=self.text))
        self.btn=Button(text="My Button", on_press=self.dismiss)  # add dismiss action
        self.layout.add_widget(self.btn)
        self.add_widget(self.layout)
```

I have also removed the line: `self.bind(on_press=self.MyButton)`. I don't think that is doing anything.

Comment: yes, you are right but actually this button change screen but in my codes not work :) My problem, after change screen auto close modal.